# How are accounts with spam profiles handled?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I stumbled upon two obviously bogus user profiles that simply serve as spam. Neither has posted anything, so they can't be flagged. Is this a common problem, and how should it be handled?

- Account #1: [Buy Google Voice Accounts](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75280/buy-google-voice-accounts)
- Account #2: [Verified PayPal Accounts](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75839/verified-paypal-accounts)

Comment: You may be interested in [this thread over at Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w). Opinions differ, but for many it's not something they address until said user actually *posts* spam. I'll go ahead and destroy these two, though.